# Form Action not Working With Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, action

I have this form:

```
<form id="main" class="form-horizontal" action="?action=convert" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="value" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter Value</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="value" id="value" placeholder="Enter value">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="from" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <select name="from-cur" id="from-cur" class="form-control">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="euro">EURO</option>
              <option value="us-dollar">US DOLLAR</option>
              <option value="swiss-franc" >SWISS FRANC</option>
              <option value="british-pound">BRITISH POUND</option>
              </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="to" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
          <select name="to-cur" id="to-cur" class="form-control">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="value" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Result</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="result" placeholder="result" value="' . $this->converter->get($this->value, $this->from, $this->to) . '">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="Convert" name="Convert" value="Convert">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

and on submit I have this jquery:

```
$('#main').submit(function(event) {
var from = $('#from-cur').val();
var to = $('#to-cur').val();
var rate;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'js/rates.json',
    data: $('#rates').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        var rates =data.rates;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < rates.length; ++i) {
            if((from ==rates[i].from) && (to==rates[i].to)){
              rate = rates[i].val
              //post rate to newindex.php

              $.post('newindex.php', 'val=' + rate, function (response) {
               });

              console.log(rate);
            }
        }



    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;//suppress natural form submission
});
```

Basically, when I submit the form I receive the data from jquery file but the action of the form never happens

```
    ?action=convert.
```

When I remove the ajax bit from the jquery code, the action fires. How can I get these two actions to fire up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have the cake and eat it too.

So you need to submit the form too

```js
$('#main').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  var from = $('#from-cur').val();
  var to = $('#to-cur').val();
  var rate;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'js/rates.json',
    data: $('#rates').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      var rates = data.rates;
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < rates.length; ++i) {
        if ((from == rates[i].from) && (to == rates[i].to)) {
          rate = rates[i].val
          //post rate to newindex.php

          $.post('newindex.php', 'val=' + rate, function(response) {});

          console.log(rate);
          $('#main')[0].submit(); // submit the actual form too
        }
      }



    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot a semicolon after:
  rate = rates[i].val

Generally this is due to Javascript plain aborting when there's a syntax error. If this isn't the error, keep looking for a syntax error. Take things out and put them back in until it works. Also, hit F12 in IE and watch the "Console" tab for errors.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve the problem. I am getting no errors on the console. I removed everything and just kept the $.ajax({ }) still the form is not firing. So it has do to with the ajax query.

Comment: put an alert('1'); after each line, and see where it stops executing. it's probably aborting at some point. There are other ways to do this, but it's the way I usually fix these things rather quickly. alert('1'); alert('2'); etc.

Comment: Thank you for the debugging tips. I will use them for sure in the future.

Comment: Also, I normally use a hidden field and just post to #.. <input id="action" type="hidden" value="convert">, something like that.

Comment: Great! You too!